# Apache2 Proxy wrong routing

Tags: apache, ubuntu-16.04, mod-proxy, apache2.4

I use apache2 as a proxy to distribute request for different URLs to different lxc containers on ubuntu 16.04 LTS

For example:

- www.adomain.com is proxied to 10.0.3.100
- www.bdomain.com is proxied to 10.0.3.101
- etc.

In principle this works but fine, but now I see a strange behaviour.

Config file bbb.adomain.com:

```
<VirtualHost bbb.adomain.com:80>
    ServerName bbb.adomain.com
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
    </Proxy>


    ProxyPass / http://10.0.3.104/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.3.104/
    <Location />
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works fine, every request for bbb.adomain.com ist proxied to 10.0.3.104

However, also requests to xxx.bdomain.com are proxied to 10.0.3.104, too. But xxx.bdomain.com is NOT configured as virtual host / servername in ANY apache .conf file.

How can I configure apache2, that any URL which is not configured as virtual host / servername is NOT proxied?

How can I debug apache2 to find out, why this domain xxx.bdomain.com is proxied?

By the way - the first apache config file is 000.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName catchall
<Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
</Location>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this basic configuration :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName bbb.adomain.com
ProxyRequests Off
ProxyPreserveHost On
<Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://10.0.3.104/
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.0.3.104/
<Location />
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Location>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxx.bdomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/example
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the following steps:

**1) Update virtual file:-**

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin admin@test.com
    ServerName mysite.com
    ServerAlias www.mysite.com
  ProxyRequests Off Order deny,allow Allow from all
 <Location />
        ProxyPass http:// mysite.com:8000/
        ProxyPassReverse http:// mysite.com:8000/
    </Location>

</VirtualHost>
```

**2) Enabling Necessary Apache Modules**

To enable these four modules, execute the following commands in succession.

```
sudo a2enmod proxy

sudo a2enmod proxy_http

sudo a2enmod proxy_balancer

sudo a2enmod lbmethod_byrequests
```

**3) To put these changes into effect, restart Apache.**

```
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```